# When I compile my code with clang, gcov throws out of memory error

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, gcov

I am trying to set up a basic project, and I want to use gcov. When I use g++, it works:

```
g++ main.cpp whatever.cpp -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
```

The output of gcov is OK:

```
gcov main.gcno 
main.gcda:cannot open data file, assuming not executed
File 'main.cpp'
Lines executed:0.00% of 20
Creating 'main.cpp.gcov'

File '/usr/include/c++/7/iostream'
Lines executed:0.00% of 1
Creating 'iostream.gcov'
```

However, I need to use clang. After running the compile command:

```
clang++-6.0 main.cpp whatever.cpp -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
```

I get the following error:

```
main.gcno:version '402*', prefer 'A73*'

gcov: out of memory allocating 16158246392 bytes after a total of 0 bytes
```

My gcov version is 7.3.0, same as gcc and g++.

Any idea what is wrong and what I can do about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `llvm-cov`? Clang has it's own coverage source code intrumentation method, currently I don't know if it is compatible with gcov.

Answer (score 11):

I faced a similar mismatching version issue when trying to generate html reports with `lcov` and xml reports with `gcovr`.

### lcov

I added the parameter `--gcov-tool gcov_for_clang.sh`.

### gcovr

I added the parameter `--gcov-executable gcov_for_clang.sh`.

### gcov_for_clang.sh

Contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec llvm-cov-6.0 gcov "$@"
```

Rationale: `lcov`'s `--gcov-tool` cannot handle the space between `llvm-cov-6.0` and `gcov`, hence the bash script indirection. Don't forget to make the file executable!

### Back to your question

I guess you simply need to replace `gcov main.gcno` by `llvm-cov-6.0 gcov main.gcno`. This isn't using LLVM's genuine source-based coverage facility but its [gcov-compatible coverage implementation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html#introduction).

### Note on compiler options

In my setup I simply pass `--coverage` as compiler option, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html) reference to get Source based code coverage report from Clang and associated utilities.

**Update:**
As noted by @Lothar in the comment the above-mentioned link now points to Source-Based Code Coverage supported by Clang Tooling, `gcov` compatible example section has been removed.

For `gcov` compatible documentation one can refer [here](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html) for the `llvm-cov gcov` command line invocation.

Comment: This once pointed to a valid version of the Clang manual but now at CLang 12 it only contains a description of the new sanitizer coverage "-fprofile-instr-generate" not the gcov format anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Lothar , have updated the answer to point to `llvm-cov gcov` documentation. But the other answer might be more relevant.